# How to Turn OFF Find My iPhone if I don't Know the ID & Password?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, unlock

It's a Pre-Owned Phone, I bought it from a Market Place.

Seller forgot to reset the iCloud Account, and I lost the Owner Contact details...

I've seen many Bypass Tricks Online, Nothing worked for me...

Finally My hope is here...

is there any experts here, Know How to Bypass the iCloud Lock to Turn OFF the Find My iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

There's a good chance you bought a stolen iPhone. I'd bring it to an Apple Store or contact Apple support:

[How to Contact Us - Apple](https://www.apple.com/contact/)

If it hasn't been reported as stolen, maybe they'll be able to help you.

I would not expect that anyone here knows the answer to this. Even if there was such an exploit, knowledge of it could make a person quite wealthy. You aren't going to find out about it on a web forum or Google search.

Comment: Apple will do nothing.  They will *especially* not help you break into the phone.

Comment: Hmm, has anyone gotten rich doing this with Android devices? I have never tried it but I see absolutely no good reason for preventing it. Stolen devices should be identified via IMEI blacklist. That a device was stolen cannot be the default assumption.

Comment: Yould get rich (for some time until you go to jail) because you would be the only who knows how to do it.

Comment: "That a device was stolen cannot be the default assumption." You're welcome to think what you'd like, but "I bought a used iPhone and the person I bought it from didn't turn off Find My iPhone and now I can't remember how to get in touch with the person I bought it from." definitely sounds like a stolen phone to me. I suspect many people would agree, but obviously not everyone. And if it's not stolen, Apple has the best chance of anyone of being able to get in.

Comment: I don't dare to speculate in this specific case. But your answer plus @Marc Wilson 's comment would lock countless legit users out of their devices when they forget their passwords. So my comment should be read: that a device was stolen cannot be Apple's default assumption when the password is not known. So at least a factory reset should be possible. Stolen phones should be blacklisted instead. But it seems we are all speculating here.

Comment: Apple makes it easy.  Prove you own the phone, they will remove whatever lock there is.  It's exactly that simple.